# Is there a relatively easy way to implement the retain/release memory management mechanism from Objective-C in Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, memory-management

The only way I can think of doing this is the create a sub class of Object and add retain/release methods that increment/decrement a counter, have an observer on this counter that invokes a deconstructor which is also in the Object subclass, after invoking the deconstructor you would free the memory using a native call.

Problem would be that all objects must extend this new subclass, not very backward compatible, can you guys think of a better way to do this?

Comment: You already have the JVM and the GC.

Comment: Yes but out of interest i'd like to know how to do this.

Comment: you don't get it. Garbage collector is much more advanced version of memory management. It works like retain release but it happens automatically without additional code. It is like ARC but even better since it detects circular dependency.

Comment: Actually it can detect those circles whith are detached from the root. This is important.

Comment: Uh, why would you want to?  Java has a built-in garbage collector.  If you need a "dealloc" like function `finalize()` is admittedly a bit flaky but works well enough for most uses.

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain what you intend to accomplish by this (other than just an intellectual exercise) we could provide better advice.

Comment: I guess manually freeing memory would reduce the strain on the GC and would improve average latency response. For example in applications like algo trading you would'nt want the GC to kick in at a critical time and delay your actions.

Comment: @user1037729 - There is no way to "manually free memory".  And the solution to GC "kicking in" at an inappropriate time is concurrent GC (which, for religious reasons, is rarely implemented).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you'd want to but to make it work with every class, have a global object that you send retain and release methods to along with the object you plan on retaining/releasing.

This global object can simply manage putting them into a collection with a retain count, which is the same as hanging on to that object, right?

```
memoryManager.retain(obj);

memoryManager.release(obj);
```

Comment: I wouldn't have a global object which manages this, each object would maintain a count of references too it. Thats why all class would have to extend the new object subclass, which it self is bad, but I can't think of a better way...

Comment: Another way would to create an interface with retain, release and destroy methods, and create a component which implements this interface and then use this component inside all the objects you want to manage the memory of manually. This would allow you to retro fit the functionality onto existing code, hence its backward compatible.

Comment: If you plan on subclassing then you plan on cutting all existing functionality short because of your base class. My solution guarantees it will work with every existing class with no modification. The result will be just as expected, regardless of whether it's going through a singleton or not.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that if you're mimicking Objective-C (and not ARC), the object does not need to keep track of what it references.  Rather the programmer keeps track of that and "manually" does retain/release as required.  No need to automate the tracking of which objects are linked.

What you really need to mimic this is a (cough) singleton that supports `retain(Object)` and `release(Object)` methods and internally manages a Map of object pointer to reference count.  The object pointer in the Map assures that the object will exist until the count goes to zero (when the Map entry will be removed).  After a count goes zero but before removing the Map entry you can invoke the object's `dealloc` method (if it has one -- test if it implements a Dealloc interface).

(But I see that this is basically the same as SomeGuy's suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

You already know that it is completely useless, because the garbage collector is taking care of everything.

In addition, retain/release is not really a garbage collection mechanism, but rather a retain counter. Objective-c offer its "garbage collector" but it is only available on OSX platform, not iOS.

To answer your question, the only way to mimic objective-c is to go deep at root of JVM. Take a look at the `sun.misc.Unsafe` class, there you can access direct memory (with some restrictions) declare variable and release them. Unfortunately I am behind a company firewall at the moment, so I cannot give you any links. Will try again later. Just google for java direct memory access and phrases like that.

Some link, I will add more as soon as I can:

- [Java Magic. sun.misc.Unsafe](http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/)
- [Direct memory access in Java](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/direct-memory-access-in-java/)

Anyway, rather than spending too much time on this, I would start reading about JVM and garbage collector tuning, you will gain skills that few people have.

Good read :-)

Comment: I'm asking to gain experience in performance tunning, cheers the links would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you'd want to do it, but here we go

```
public class ReferenceCountedObject
{
    private int referenceCount;

    public ReferenceCountedObject()
    {
        this.retain();
    }

    public synchronized ReferenceCountedObject retain()
    {
        referenceCount++;
        return this;
    }

    public synchronized void release()
    {
        if (referenceCount == 1)
        {
            this.dealloc();
        }
        else
        {
            referenceCount--;
        }
    }

    protected void dealloc()
    {
        // memory will be freed by GC
    }
}
```

Comment: The object may be freed by the garbage collector if no one reference it, no matter how big the retainCount is.

Comment: @Leonardo But that's what you want.  In Objective-C, if you have no references and a retain count >= 1, you have a memory leak because there is no way to do the final release.